Problems with the videoeditor and rendering PNG animations
I am currently exporting a 1205 frame animation that was rendered in PNGs, I would like the exact render image to be converted into an MP4, but I have tried a range of suggested settings, different formats etc (including the most suggested: FFmpeg, MPEG-4, H264, perceptially lossless, etc. But whenever I exported the animation in the video editor I got a lot of artifacts in dark scenes due to the compression. I then changed the output quality to high quality and all the artifacts were cleared up but now the animation lighting is completely different.
I am very new to rendering but not to blender in general. Could someone help me understand what is going on, I have spent many hours trying to fix this and I am having no luck finding anything on the internet as it differs from case to case.
Thanks

Are you referring to the problem described in this video?

Yes, but i fixed it using high quality output, but when i changed it to this setting the light areas remained normal but the dark areas just got super dark. I just dont get why the blender editor is changing the way the frames look, surely there is a way to export a collection of PNGs so it looks the same as you render it.

Can you show where you change the “high-quality output“ setting? I’m not familiar with it. Also please show examples of the input PNG’s and a screenshot from the two output videos.

Also show a comparison of a frame before/after video encoding. Make sure you use the appropriate Color Management in your scene and on your VSE strip.

...actually, if the PNGs are rendered with Color Management which I suppose, then you probably have to render the video sequence without any Color Management on top of it, i.e. it should be set to View Transform > Standard and Look > None.

Hello, so the actual render is fine, but its just combining it to an mp4, the pngs are set to "follow scene", they are set to RGBA, 16 colour depth, 0% compression. for post processing they are using compositing only and 0 dither. I am just stuck on what settings to use for converting to mp4 without losing any quality and keeping it exactly as it looks in the png.

For the conversion to mp4, i am converting to ffmpeg, RGB, MPEG-4 encoding, H264 codec, lossless quality with good encoding speed. keyframe interval is 18 (which I dont know what it does) and post processing is using sequencer and 0 dither again.
I am using the exact same resolution and aspect ratio, as well as the FPS as the original animation.
Below is a picture of a frame when converted to mp4 vs its original render.
https://gyazo.com/9b09e491fb166b135813c025b7eadaa7
https://gyazo.com/8e31fab0abac527311bf0f82312d074b

You can see there is a lot more noise. I have spent a lot of the day trying to figure out different combinations of settings but most of the examples of the different settings have been overriden as i have used the same directory for the outputs.
